# How can I return value of a dictionary that sits inside a database table, using an SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following database table, let's call it `features`:

```
 id      date       info 
 1   2024-02-15    {'ccy':'CHF', 'mic':'blvd', 'market_type': 56}   
 2   2024-02-15    {'ccy':'AUD', 'mic':'kkl', 'market_type': 33}
 ..
```

I would like to filter the rows where the `market_type` is not in a given list. Let's say the list is `[1,2,3,4,56]`

My query reads something like this:

```
   SELECT * FROM features WHERE CAST(info ->> 'market_type' AS INTEGER) NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 56);
```

And this returns the rows where the`market_type` is not in the list.

But now I would like to return the `market_type` instead of the entire row. Any ideas how this can be done? Or if it can be done at all?

Comment: Does this work? `select info->'market_type' from features ...the rest` Please clarify your question.

Comment: Works! thank you ^^

Comment: It's called JSON not a dictionary. Is it `json` or `jsonb`? Side note: `::int` is the shorter way to cast.